# Why doesn't perspective property work for my element?

Tags: html, css, transform

I've established `perspective` and `rotateY(60deg)`to my parent element. But this one looks like it's not in 3D space. What's wrong? Thanks

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(60deg) perspective(200px);
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: persective BEFORE rotation

Comment: @Temani Afif I'd never have guessed. Thanks